# Can't load image in qt android

Tags: android, qt, qt5, qimage, qfile

I have an address to my mobile image like
/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1.jpg 
or
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1.jpg

I use QFile and QImage for read that

- when read image with qfile, it can't open that but exist function return true
- qimage also can't load image
- I also use file:// before upper addresses but not worked.

I use qt 5.8 and api 23(android 6) and i make android manifest file and take permission for read and write to storage.

Comment: Only requesting permissions in manifest file is not enough anymore since Android 6. Did you adapt for modern times?

Comment: No, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to using too large resolution images.  If you set the sourceSize property, it scales down youre image to the desired resolution.

Comment: Where i should set sourceSize property?

Comment: Image QML property. 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#sourceSize-prop

Comment: When i load image with qimage it return false. I don't think it is about image size.